# flex Css doesn't support in Safari , iPhone 5 and mobile Browser Webviews

Tags: ios, css, webview, safari, flexbox

Those are HTML:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar text-center" role="toolbar">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1111111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111111111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111111111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 11111</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Link 1</a>
    </div>
```

Those are CSS:

```
.btn-toolbar{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.btn-toolbar .btn{
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
```

flex Css doesn't support in Safari , iPhone 5, IOS 6  and mobile Browser Webviews. I use browser support but it's still not working. Any kind of solution please. I don't want to use any fixed width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.btn-toolbar{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.btn-toolbar .btn{
  -webkit-box-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-box-flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-grow: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}
```